# Count number of cells with any value (string or number) in a column in Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have several columns in  Google Spreadsheet.

I would like to count how many cells have a value (number or string) and display that number at the top of the column.

**For example:**

---

Hello

---

World

---

123

---

Some string

---

The above column would give me the answer of "4"

I have not managed to find a formula that does this.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152704/google-spreadsheet-count-if-contains-a-string

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In the cell you want your result to appear, use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A200,"<>")
```

That will count all cells which have a value and ignore all empty cells in the range of A1 to A200.

Comment: That is perfect! I am not aloud to add a +1 for you due to my status being less that 15 apparently.

Comment: I had to use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: In LibreOffice I had to use ; also.

Comment: Google's COUNTA() is better

Answer (score 19):

You could also use `=COUNTA(A1:A200)` which requires no conditions.

From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en):

> COUNTA counts all values in a dataset, including those which appear
>   more than once and text values (including zero-length strings and
>   whitespace). To count unique values, use COUNTUNIQUE.

Comment: How to count non empty cells?

Comment: COUNTA considers empty strings as non-empty cells.

Comment: @TracyFu yes it does: zero-length strings and empty strings are the same thing. It is noted that they are counted in the answer using an excerpt from Google’s own explanation.

Answer (score 6):

An additional trick beside using =COUNTIF(...) and =COUNTA(...) is:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A2:C100)
```

That will count all the empty cells.

This is useful for:

- empty cells that doesn't contain data
- formula that return blank or null
- survey with missing answer fields which can be used for diff criterias

Answer (score 4):

Shorter and dealing with a column (entire, not just a section of a column):

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```

[COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991)

Beware, a cell containing just a space would be included in the count.

Answer (score 0):

The `SUBTOTAL` function can be used if you want to get the count respecting any filters you use on the page.

`=SUBTOTAL(103, A1:A200)`

will help you get count of non-empty rows, respecting filters.

103 - is similar to `COUNTA`, but ignores empty rows and also respects filters.

**Reference** : [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649?hl=en)