# Google Sheet Wildcard not working with COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets

It should be simple, but it's not working.  It seems like the same question as [Google Spreadsheet, Count IF contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152704/google-spreadsheet-count-if-contains-a-string) but it still doesn't work. And the semicolon mentioned in the responses of that question just gets eaten, so I'm guessing that's an old format.

Basically I have a column of years (it's not designated as a date column) and I want to return total decade counts. I put:

=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "200?")

I thought that would return a count value for everything from 2000-2009, but it just returns zero. If I remove the wildcard and make it one specific year, I do get a count for that year, so it's the wildcard that's the problem. I've tried "?" and "*" and neither work. What am I doing wrong here? Everything I've read says, including the [Google COUNTIF documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) says this should work.

[Screenshot of my spreadsheet formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iV9Y.png)

Comment: why don't you check if it's between 2000 and 2009?

Comment: That's a really good point. I guess I just got tunnel vision on using a wildcard. Now that you say that, I'm guessing that wildcards don't work with numbers, only strings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are misreading the documentation.

The documentation [as referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090691/google-sheet-wildcard-not-working-with-countif) mentions wildcards *only* in the context **If `range` contains text to check against,**.

Number formats can however be changed to Text "on the fly" (ie within a formula), such as suggested by [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091586/1505120), or a different approach taken suited to the format, as in a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090691/google-sheet-wildcard-not-working-with-countif#comment89169815_51090691).