# Range of Cells as Criteria for COUNTIFS Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list that contains multiple items. However, each item has different variants.

I want to sum all occurrences of each item, regardless of the variant.

I am using the COUNTIFS function in Google Sheets but for the criteria, I want to input a range that is an array of strings.

```
=countifs(!A:A,("B:B"),!C:C,"small")
```

Where column B includes a list of different variant names and column C is sizing.

For example:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apples | apples | small |
| apples | applez | small |
| applez | applees | small |
| appleees |  | small |
| oranges |  | small |

In this case I would want the result to = 4 because there were four total instances in column A where the criteria was met (using any string/row in column B) and since all sizes were small.

I was able to get the result I wanted using this formula however it is extremely cumbersome as there are many variants and they are constantly updated/changed concurrently in column B:

```
=countifs(A:A,"item variant 1",C:C,"small")
+countifs(A:A,"item variant 2",C:C,"small")
+countifs(A:A,"item variant 3",C:C,"small")
+countifs(A:A,"item variant 4",C:C,"small")
+countifs(A:A,"item variant 5",C:C,"small")
```

Seeking any improvement at all from there, I tried listing the variants within a range itself (making sure to use a semicolon for Google Sheets based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924211/8743612)) and couldn't get that to work either:

```
=countifs(A:A,{"item variant 1";"item variant 2";"item variant 3";"item variant 4";"item variant 5"},C:C,"small")
```

In the above case, it only counts instances of first variant mentioned in the range (in this case item variant 1).

Comment: not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, are you trying to count how many different inputs are in Column A according to a given criteria in Column C? you didn't even mention why Column B exists and the formula you say is working didn't take Column B in consideration...

Answer (score 0):

while you said the expected output is 4,
I can only see 2 unique items matching for a count of 3(apples, applez)
& orange has zero match
& appl**eee**s not a match to appl**ee**s

formula:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(filter(A:A,(C:C="small")*(REGEXMATCH(A:A,TEXTJOIN("|",1,B2:B))))))
```

- 

Alternate formula:

```
=COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A)*(C2:C="small"),IFERROR(vlookup(A2:A6,B:B,1,)),)))
```

[image]

Comment: "while you said the expected output is 4, I can only see 2 unique items matching for a count of 3" --

In column A there are a total of 4 instances of words listed in column B.

Comment: 'apples' 2 instances are matching and 'applez' 1 instance is matching. can you help me out with the expected 4th instance?

Comment: @HeidiB. I agree that there are only three instances, A5 has 3 "e", and your options have 1 and 2 "e"

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

Assume that your data are always arranged as {ITEMS,VARIANTS,SIZES},

In this formula, you can adjust data range and search criteria according to the values in the last `()` (current values are `$A:$C` and `"small"`),

this formula...

1. uses `BYROW()` to iterate `VARIANTS` column and...
2. use `QUERY()` to filter `ITEMS` column for matches according to `VARIANT` and... `FINDSIZE` as criteria,
3. `COUNT()` the output of the filters by `QUERY()`, `SUM()` the `RESULTS` of all filters to get `3`, since only `apples` and `applez` of the given `VARIANTS` has matches. (`applees` in `VARIANTS` has only `2 'e's` while `appleees` in `ITEMS` has `3 'e's`, makes it a non-match)

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(RANGE,FINDSIZE,
  LAMBDA(DATA,FINDSIZE,
   LAMBDA(ITEMS,VARIANTS,SIZES,
    LAMBDA(RESULTS,
     SUM(RESULTS)
    )(
     BYROW(VARIANTS,LAMBDA(VARIANT,
      LAMBDA(FILTER,
       SUM(IFNA(FILTER,0))
      )(QUERY({ITEMS,SIZES},"SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1='"&VARIANT&"' AND Col2='"&FINDSIZE&"' LABEL COUNT(Col1)''",0))
     ))
    )
   )(INDEX(DATA,,1),QUERY({RANGE},"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL",0),LOWER(INDEX(DATA,,2)))
  )(QUERY({RANGE},"SELECT Col1,Col3 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col3 IS NOT NULL",0),LOWER(FINDSIZE))
 )($A:$C,"small")
)
```

If you don't concern the accessibility of the range and criteria, here is a shorter version:

```
=SUM(BYROW(B:B,LAMBDA(VARIANT,IFNA(IF(VARIANT="",0,QUERY({A:A,C:C},"SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1='"&VARIANT&"' AND Col2='small' LABEL COUNT(Col1)''",0)),0))))
```